# Visual studio not showing unity function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am novice to unity learning and while writing transform.position VS not showing any function of unity.
my code is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public float control;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
       //while i try to write transform.position below this comment no function is showing
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio Tools for Unity? If yes are you using solution created by unity?

Comment: you can get vs tools for unity from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity)

Comment: @Logman: I am using Visual Studio. Are you referring to some Unity plugin in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. To have intellisense with Unity you need to have Visual Studio Tools for Unity plugin installed into your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 12):

Try to set your external tool editor in unity apps from menu Edit/Preferences/Exernal Tools, in my case as default it set to visual studio 2010 when im using VS 2019 that make it open as selector version and unity function is unknow by VS. So i change that to VS 2019, and that show the unity function.

Comment: If you are using Unity 2020, you may also need to Regenerate project files (.csproj) for Embedded packages and Local packages.

Answer (score 0):

To have intellisense with Unity you need to have Visual Studio Tools for Unity plugin installed into your Visual Studio.